# Force to use comma as a decimal separator in inputText field

Tags: jsf, primefaces, decimal

I'm having a inputText where a number having a comma as a decimal separator is expected. The backend `amount` field is a `BigDecimal`, so the actual number going to the backend should be in the form `100.00` while I want the UI to show `100,00` and not accept `100.00`.

I have looked at the `inputNumber` component which kinda does what I want, but we do not have that dependency in our project, so it's out of discussion.

I have also tried adding `<f:convertNumber pattern="#0,00" />`, but that does not help or I don't know how to use it...

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<p:inputText id="grossPayment"
    styleClass="greyText boldText"
    converterMessage="#{nts['grossPaymentNumbers']}"
    requiredMessage="#{nts['grossPaymentRequired']}"
    required="#{bean.profile.salary.required}"
    value="#{bean.profile.salary.amount}">
    <f:validator
        disabled="#{!bean.profile.salary.required}"
        validatorId="positiveNumberValidator" />
</p:inputText>
```

Comment: _"I have looked at the inputNumber component which kinda does what I want, but we do not have that dependency in our project, so it's out of discussion."_ Why? It is in PrimeFaces and `p:inputText` is also PrimeFaces

Comment: No. It is in Primefaces Extensions. Or at least, I am not able to see it as I'm typing.

Comment: Look at the PrimeFaces showcase. There is one there... http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/inputNumber.xhtml